# Idiomatic function names for Elixir/Phoenix controller helpers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm writing some `get` helpers in my Phoenix web app. In rails, you would generally name (or have method missing) helpers like `find_account_by_email(email)`, etc.

With pattern matching seeming so core to Elixir/Erlang, I'm wondering if I'm better of writing my helpers like:

```
def get_account({email: email}) do
  # ...
end
```

Phoenix stubs out a `get_account(id)` method, so it feels to me that reusing the name with pattern matching is more idiomatic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Welcome to Stack Overflow!*

While [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) might be called the "Rails for Elixir", the design patterns and the architecture considerations are very different. Exposing random functions that *"might be used for a bunch of things"* isn't really part of the philosophy.

---

But the good part is, that if your use-case does call for something like this, it's very easy to extend existing functionality using Macros, Behaviours or Protocols. **For your simple use-case, you can indeed create a generic method** (or a set of methods), but I would lose the `tuple`:

```ex
defmodule Account do
  def get(clauses) do
    Repo.get_by(Account, clauses)
  end
end
```

You can call it using:

```ex
Account.get(email: "user@example.com")
```

But I would argue if replacing one one-liner with another, truly added enough value to your codebase to warrant it.

---

<sup>**Side Note:** *I [actually created a library](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ecto_rut) to add Rails-style model helpers to Ecto schemas in Elixir apps to ease-in Rails developers to Phoenix, exposing methods similar to what active-record does. Also see the [note about complex queries](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ecto_rut#not-for-complex-queries).*</sup>

Comment: "But I would argue to see if it truly added enough value to your codebase by replacing one one-liner with another.", by this do you imply I should be using Repo directly in my other code? It actually getting called from a background genserver and including Repo everywhere seems like it's breaking the encapsulation laid out by phoenix's "contexts".

Comment: I agree that repeating `Repo` calls again and again can be tiring and prone to bugs, so ideally you should have a module encapsulating **important and repeated** queries. But for one-off calls encapsulating the logic in another method does not make sense. You should just use existing library methods.

Comment: Also `YourApp.Repo` actually does behave like a separate context in Phoenix applications by abstracting out how your application interacts with a database or another schema. Unless your queries are getting very complicated, you shouldn't abstract them out further in another context.